# Discord.js - Bot join command author Voice Channel

Tags: discord.js

I am making a discord.js bot and i want that the bot join the voice channel of the command author. My code its actually this:

```
    client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "join")){
    const vchannel = message.member.voiceChannel
    vchannel.join()
  }
});
```

Im using Discord.js Ver. 11 and when i run the bot and execute the command it says: Cannot read property "join"

Comment: What is the problem with your code? In what way it doesn't work? Try to explain this a little bit. I'm telling you this because as it's written it's hard to understand what's your problem: this seems to be valid code (for discord.js@v11, in v12 it needs to be different). Please [edit] your answer and add what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `message.member.voiceConnection` or `message.member.voiceChannel`, i recently learned this:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "join")){
    const { voiceChannel } = message.member;

    if (!voiceChannel) {
        return message.reply('please join a voice channel first!');
    }
    voiceChannel.join()
}
```

And, of course, please look at discord.js guide if you haven't allready. If  you need help, just refer to it in most cases. They have a tut for [a music bot](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/miscellaneous-examples.html#play-music-from-youtube) which is really simple (no queue) but teaches you how to play music.
It worked for me, I'm guessing it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

So the property `member` of the class `Message` has no property `voiceChannel`.
You should instead do this:

```js
let  voiceChannel  = message.member.voice.channel;

if (!voiceChannel){return message.reply(' Please join a voice channel first!');}

voiceChannel.join();
```

source: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome